# Angular and posting Data to a Form

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-forms

I am new to programing overall and this is my first try at using Angular so please take that into consideration when you answer.  It was suggested that I attempt to build a To Do list using Angular to learn more about java script and I am stuck on how to get my data (to do items) to post on my form when the Add Task button is clicked.  The form resets so I know the button is "working" but my item does not render.  If anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it.

Below is are the relevant pieces of my code.  Thank you in advance for your help.

html:

```
   <form ng-submit= "addTodo()" class= "list-group-item">
     <input type= "text" placeholder= "Add your task here" ng-model= "newTodo"/>
      <select ng-model= "todoPriority">
       <option value= "normal">Low</option>
       <option value= "normal">Medium</option>
       <option value= "normal">High</option>
     </select>
    <button ng-click= "addTodo()">Add Task to List</button>
  </form>
```

app.js

```
        (function(){
  var app = angular.module('Todo-app', []);
    app.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope){
        $scope.todos= [];

        $scope.todoPriority= 'normal';

        $scope.addTodo= function(){
          var newTodo={
            done: false,
            text: $scope.todoText,
            priority: $scope.todoPriority
          };
            $scope.todos.push(newTodo);
            $scope.todoText = '';
            $scope.todoPriority = 'normal';
        };


        $scope.getTotal= function(){
      return $scope.todos.length;
    };

   $scope.removeTodo= function(start){

      $scope.todos.splice(start, 1);
    };

    $scope.move= function(index, direction){
      if (direction === 'up'){
        if (index === 0){
          return;
          }
          index = index -1;
        }
      if (direction === 'down'){
         if (index === $scope.todos.length -1) {
         return;
         }
      }
    var todo= $scope.todos[index];
    $scope.todos.splice(index+2,0, todo);
    $scope.todos.splice(index, 1);
    };
 });

});
```